# Http POST.. why doesn't print anything?

Tags: c, http, networking, pcap, sniffing

I'm writing a sniffer program with the pcap library that checks the http traffic. I succeed when I m looking for GET messages or status codes but I don't know why it doesn't work for the post requests.
I tried to use wireshark and I saw that for POST requests, in addition to the http protocol there is also an Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded "protocol".
When I try to print the content of the payload I didn't get results or I get strange characters.. so I was thinking that maybe the problem is this "Line-based.." stuff..
Any idea of the possible cause?

Answer (score 1):

The strange characters may be from utf-8 encoded as opposed to ascii encoded POSTs. It also depends which applications you are looking to capture, as some Flash apps use POST requests but encrypt them to prevent tampering.

Comment: I'm parsing the packet payload of the tcp protocol in order to find the "POST" string but I don't find nothing..

Comment: 90e2e550 is from one packet of 538 bytes

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** [See my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479122/strange-characters-in-packets/4480672#4480672)

This is what I'm capturing with tcpdump. What do you see?

```
POST /xml/crud/posttest.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: www.snee.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Fedora/3.6.12-1.fc13 Firefox/3.6.12
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.html
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 21

fname=test&lname=test
```