# strange characters in packets

Tags: c, http, networking, pcap

I'm writing a sniffer for http packets with libpcap.
Sometimes printing the content of the http payload I get strange characters.. do you know what could they be?

*xNT:���3�@�"P#1u`��$%S{M��

or

�~�tsE��}>a�����}/���`�▒�A�y

Thanks, for the answers.

If the header is in plain text so the problem is my code.

Anyway, can a POST request be coded in base64?

Answer (score 2):

In `utils_http.c` you have the following function:

```
static int handle_tcp(const struct tcphdr *tcp, int len)
{
  char buf[PCAP_SNAPLEN];
  memcpy(buf, tcp + 1, len - sizeof(*tcp));
  DEBUG("DANY TCPDs tcp string: %s",buf);
  if (0 == handle_http(buf, len - sizeof(*tcp)))
    return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

This is making the assumption that the TCP payload always starts 20 bytes after the beginning of the TCP header (always 20 because `sizeof(*tcp) == 20`). This doesn't take into account any TCP options. If you receive a packet with TCP options (which are very common), `handle_http()` will have the binary-encoded TCP options at the beginning of its buffer which might be what you're seeing.

Try something like this instead:

```
static int handle_tcp(const struct tcphdr *tcp, int len)
{
  char buf[PCAP_SNAPLEN];
  memcpy(buf, (void*)tcp + tcp->doff*4, len - tcp->doff*4);
  DEBUG("DANY TCPDs tcp string: %s",buf);
  if (0 == handle_http(buf, len - tcp->doff*4))
    return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Or better yet, I have no idea why you're constantly making dozens of copies of your buffer every chance you get. You can just pass pointers around unless I'm missing something:

```
static int handle_tcp(const struct tcphdr *tcp, int len) {
  return handle_http((void*)tcp + tcp->doff*4, len - tcp->doff*4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably binary data that your display font has no characters for. HTTP does not necessarily transport text, it could be images or any other form of raw binary the client requested. Hard to say without seeing the rest of the TCP package.

Comment: ah ok got it. Anyway, any HTTP header is always in plain text? or could it be encoded in some way? thx

Comment: HTTP header is absolutely always plain text in ASCII encoding.

Comment: By the way, note that the binary data you're seeing might be an image or something, but it's also possible that it's text with a transport encoding like gzip.

Comment: @cenos: Header fields cannot contain raw binary, because control characters are forbidden as per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Message-Headers).

Comment: ok I got it. So I think there something wrong in my code.. because I'm able to see the GET requests but not the POST

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) should tell you the type of payload. The HTTP headers should also say whether compression is used.

Compare what you get with http://web-sniffer.net/ or use something like Wireshark

Comment: yes I was using wireshark, the problem maybe is in my code :( but it's very strange..